# ompl GetMotionPlan

Tags: ros, ompl, ompl-ros-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm working whit ompl motion plan service, in:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ompl_ros_interface/Tutorials/Specifying%20pose%20goals

when I do:

```
 ros::ServiceClient service_client = nh.serviceClient<motion_planning_msgs::GetMotionPlan>("/ompl_planning/plan_kinematic_path");
  service_client.call(request,response);
  if(response.error_code.val != response.error_code.SUCCESS)
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Motion planning failed");
  }
```

Always obtain: response.error_code.val != response.error_code.SUCCESS === FALSE

And if you see the planning log, you can see:

```
[ERROR] [1352218229.018731999, 4531.226000000]: client wants service /ompl_planning/plan_kinematic_path to have md5sum dc1bde6dccfb9e1ff4f7ed84e081f964, but it has e7f04013c167d0703692fec8a86b22ef. Dropping connection.
```

What this means? what is the problem??

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47592/ompl-getmotionplan/) by [Sanxano](https://answers.ros.org/users/1103/sanxano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2012-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is ros versions.

In electric does't exist motion_planning_msgs package. All necesary classes are in arm_navigation_msgs

motion_planning_msgs::GetMotionPlan --change--> arm_navigation_msgs::GetMotionPlan.

---

Originally posted by [Sanxano](https://answers.ros.org/users/1103/sanxano/) with karma: 70 on 2012-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0